# Losing animation after creating a component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, material-ui

I want to use the 'Tabs' component created in 'Material UI'.

'Material UI' tabs demo: https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/

```
render() {
  <div>
    <Tabs
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    >
      <Tab label="First label" />
      <Tab label="Second label" />
    </Tabs>
  </div>
 }


 handleChange = () => {
   this.setState({
     value: !this.state.value
   })
 }
```

When I'm using the code above, then everything is fine, when I click on the second or first tab, then I can see the nice animation of changing the position of a tab.

But when I would like to create a new component like:

```
const NewTabs = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Tabs
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.handleChange}
      >  
        <Tab label={props.firstLabel} />
        <Tab label={props.secondLabel} />
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NewTabs
```

And pass data like:

```
render() {
  <div>
    <NewTabs 
      value={this.state.value}
      handleChange={this.handleChange}
      firstLabel= "First test label"
      secondLabel = "Second test label"
     />
  </div>
}

handleChange = () => {
   this.setState({
     value: !this.state.value
   })
 }
```

Then everything works, but the animation of changing the position of the tab is not visible.

Why is this happening, and how could I see the animation if I want to use a new created component?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because the state is held in the parent and it will cause a complete re-render every time the state changes so you wont see an animation.

You could have the state in the `NewTabs` instead of passing it in from the parent?

```
class NewTabs extends React.Component{

   handleChange = () => {
      this.setState({
        value: !this.state.value
      })
    }

  render(){
   return (
    <div>
      <Tabs
        value={state.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      >  
        <Tab label={props.firstLabel} />
        <Tab label={props.secondLabel} />
      </Tabs>
    </div>

   )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    <div>
      <NewTabs 
        firstLabel= "First test label"
        secondLabel = "Second test label"
       />
    </div> 
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought about it, but I will have to keep this state in the parent, because of some different things. So maybe will you have a different idea?

Comment: Have you tried giving the `Tab` elements a unique ID?

Comment: It not helping. The same result

Comment: This sounds related to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775893/react-child-component-loses-animation-upon-re-render. Altho that was caused by the withStyles method.  Still not clear how to fix if useStyles is needed, or in the use case you're providing.