# React child component loses animation upon re-render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, css-transitions, react-props

I have a React application using Material UI with a component (which we can call `DatePicker`) shown below, sneakily changed for demo purposes.

[image: Ripple demonstration]

Material UI animates clicks and other interactions with its components. When clicking a radio button that has already been selected, or a "time button" which doesn't change state, this animation is visible above. However, when such a click changes the state, the animation get interrupted.

I can see why this happens from a technical perspective; the `DatePicker` component calls `setMinutes`, which is a property passed in from its parent (where the state lives). This is a `React.useState` variable, which then updates its corresponding `minutes` variable. Minutes is then passed into `DatePicker`, which re-renders due to a prop change.

If state lived within `DatePicker` then this problem shouldn't rear its head; however, `DatePicker` is one part of a much larger form which dictates the contents of a table in the parent. To generate rows for this table, the parent must have this information.

Below is a sample reconstruction of the parent:

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [minutes, setMinutes] = React.useState(15);
    const [radioOption, setRadioOption] = React.useState('Thank You');
    // Many other state variables here to hold other filter information

    return (<div>
        <DatePicker minutes={minutes} setMinutes={setMinutes} radioOption={radioOption} setRadioOption={setRadioOption}/>
    </div>);
};
```

And here a sample reconstruction of `DatePicker`:

```
const DatePicker: React.FC<DatePickerProps> = props => {
    const {minutes, setMinutes, radioOption, setRadioOption} = props;
    return (<div>
        <Radios value={radioOption} onChange={val => setRadioOption(val)}/>
        <Minutes value={minutes} onChange{val => setMinutes(val)}/>
    </div>);
};
```

I'm not sure what the best practice is in this situation, but I get the distinct feeling that this is not it. Does anyone have any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your comment, Ryan Cogswell. I did create a code sandbox, and found that the problem was not about React state management as much as what I was doing *beyond* what I provided in my question.

I was using the [withStyles HOC](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api) to wrap my component, in a way similar to `const StyledDatePicker = withStyles(styles)(DatePicker)`. I then used that styled element and put properties (`minutes`, etc) on that.

It turns out that using the unstyled `DatePicker` resolves this issue. I troubleshooted this further, and found that I had created the "Styled" component within the "render" method of the parent, meaning every time a prop change was pushed up the chain, the parent would re-render and the entire "Styled" component type would be created again (or so I believe). This would break reference integrity, which explains the "drop and recreate" behaviour.

This teaches the valuable lesson of keeping components small and using code sandboxes for troubleshooting. Thanks again!

For anyone interested, here is the [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-frost-p0qte?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) used for testing.

Comment: Thanks for your follow-up.  However, is there a way around this while still using the withStyles HOC wrapper?  Another user has encountered a diff problem but with the same root cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56719846/losing-animation-after-creating-a-component